# Gson en Release funciona diferente que en Debug en Android

Tags: java, android, gson

Me encuentro que una app donde cargo unos datos de `json` con la libreria `gson` a una lista de objeto personalizado, en modo `realease` no llena la lista.
A que es debido?

Este es mi objeto:

```
public class Route {

    private String title;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te muestra en el _Log_? Mientras lo ejecutas en tu teléfono puedes ver que es lo que pasa en la consola de _Log_, en caso que no te muestre nada, utiliza los _Log.d_ antes, durante y después de llenar tu lista.

Comment: x4mp73r me temo que ya encontrado el problema, no tengo anotado @serializeName a los campos. Parece ser que en Debug se lo come tal cual y en Release sin anotación añade null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213494/android-debug-and-release-builds-having-different-results

Comment: En este caso no entiendo porque el -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta respuesta de [SO](http://You%20have%20ProGuard%20enabled%20in%20your%20release%20build%20type%20-%20minifyEnabled%20true.%20It%20obfuscates%20the%20code%20by%20changing%20class/variable%20names.%20%20You%20should%20annotate%20your%20class%20properties,%20so%20Gson%20knows%20what%20to%20look%20for:) comentan que si se tiene asignado en la versión `release` la directiva `minifyEnabled`

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
}
```

El compilador ofuscará los nombres de las variables para que ocupen menos espacio por eso que en el objeto se debe especificar la referencia del campo para así `gson` pueda meter los datos automáticamente.

> @SerializedName("nombre_campo_json")

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class Route {
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesante =0 No sabía que esto provocaba que no funcionara ejecutando la aplicación normalmente o que funcionara únicamente en Debug.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, simplemente quería añadir que es posible utilizar la anotacíon _@Expose_ en lugar de @SerializedName("nombre") si el nombre de la variable es el mismo que del json que se quiere serializar/deserializar